# Finding bed on server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-spigot

I had `/sethome` set but removed it after putting a bed there. I died but had not respawned at the bed and `/home` wont take me there either. Server admin is willing to help so are there any commands to locate my bed? Even a command to locate all beds will be useful as it is a small server. Or is there a way to see old `/home` coordinates to find my bed?

Comment: Did you sleep in the bed after placing it? I think the spawn only gets set if you sleep in it, but I could be wrong (usually am).

Comment: @KyleRone You are correct.  The bed must be slept in to set the spawn point.  Another consideration is that if the bed is obstructed, the default spawn point for the world is used instead.

Comment: `/sethome` and `/home` are not existing commands. I guess there is some mod installed that adds it? If yes, which one?

Comment: If you are using Essentials, `/homes` will display all existing homes. Check for `/home bed` which is automatically set when a Bed is placed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set the bed properly you and the admins can access it properly. However, depending on their config you may need to have slept in it in order to get saved. Also it is possible to have it deactivated in the config completely. You can only try now...

For you:

```
/homes (display all homes)
/home bed (teleport to your last bed)
```

For admins:

```
/home <your name>:bed (teleports them to your bed, if one is set)
/home <your name>: (shows a list of your homes)
```

The `:` is important or else it won't work.

In case you don't have set your bed home properly and the server has a logging plugin the admins can look up when and where you have placed a bed. It's a more painful way, but it should work. I've done that several times on my server already. The command for that depends on the plugin they're using.